# How spark driver transfer socket object to worker?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a question about spark. If i define a long-time socket connection to remote server on spark driver, i can also use the socket to communicate to remote server on spark worker.How spark do this?

for example, i define a redis client on spark driver, i also can read or write data through the redis client on spakr worker

```scala
val redisClient = Jedis.RedisClient(host, port)
rdd1.map(x => {
  val value = redisClient.get(x)
  value
})
```

Maybe redis is not the exactly right example. I want to know if the spark can transfer my long-time socket connection from driver to worker.

Comment: There is no way to "transfer" a socket itself across network, using Spark or whatever (generally in Spark you want to provide the serializable settings to open the resource, not the non-serializable resource itself). Looks like an X/Y question ...

Comment: yeal，I have figure out what happens in my project

Comment: Because the redis service was designed as static object. So the redis service is both inited in driver and worker

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that since a socket connection is not serializable, it cannot be transferred across the network.

Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you may be able to transfer metadata sufficient to establish a socket connection on the worker, which would allow the workers to each establish arbitrarily many connections, if you want to allow the workers to communicate with Redis, for example.

Answer (score 0):

RedisClient is not serializable, thus your Driver cannot pass it to your Executors.
Try this:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(partition => {
  val redisClient = Jedis.RedisClient(host, port)
  partition.map(redisClient.get)
})
```

That way, you're creating your client on each Executor. No serde

Hope it helps